# The trace of one matrix on the image or kernel of another

Tags: linear-algebra, trace

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are two *commuting* linear maps $V \to V$. Then $A$ preserves the image and kernel of $B$, and its trace restricted to these subspaces do not depend on a choice of basis. Is there a formula for either of these traces that is basis independent, say as a trace of some polynomial in $A, B, \dots$? Or slightly weaker, is there a way to compute these numbers while choosing only a basis of $V$ (thus making $A$ and $B$ into matrices), but not a basis of $\operatorname{im} B$ or $\ker B$?

Comment: Trace never depends on basis..

Comment: @Exodd which is why this question makes sense?

Comment: The kind of formula it sounds like you want seems like it would be continuous in $A$ and $B$, which the number you're trying to compute is not (the dimension of the image and kernel can change).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan This is a good point but I would be happy if there was a family of different formulas depending on the relevant $\operatorname{rank}$s, eg at the two extremes the answers are $0$ and $\operatorname{tr} A$.